# ASP.NET Core RequireClaim "scope" with multiple scopes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm developing an authorization system on ASP.NET Core 2.1 which requires both resource level and scope adherence before granting access.  That is, I must be an author of a book (there can be multiple), and a must have the necessary scopes ("write.book", "read.book", "delete.book", etc).  I successfully configured JWT in `Startup.cs`, and receive `401s` when invalid tokens are passed.  The issue I'm running into is enforcing the scopes.  `policy.RequireClaim("scope", "write.book")` works when the access token only requires the one required scope, but always fails the access token contains multiple scopes `"write.book delete.book"`.  How can I configure a policy to require a list of scopes which could be a subset of scopes an access token contains?  I'm not seeing any `Policy` methods which accepts a list of scopes, so I'm assuming the framework is just performing a string comparison, which is why the authorization is failing. `write.book != write.book delete.book`.  To clarify, if the policy only requires one scope `write.book`, but multiple are present in the access token `write.book delete.book`, the authorization fails.

The code below only works if the access token contains one scope, and fails if multiple are present.

```
authorization.AddPolicy("writeBookPolicy", policy => {
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer")
      .RequireClaim("scope", "write.book").Build();
});

{"scope": "write.book"} // Works
{"scope": "write.book delete.book"} //Fails
```

Comment: have you tried specifying `RequireClaim` twice? `RequireClaim("scope", "write.book").RequireClaim("scope", "delete.book")` ?

Comment: How about `.RequireClaim("scope", "write.book", "delete.book")`?

Comment: The issue is that the endpoint only requires "write.book", but the access token contains both "write.book" and "delete.book".  Having both scopes in the access token is what's causing the authorization to fail.

Comment: How are you setting the scopes on the token? The each scopes should be defined as its own property: `{"scope": "write.book", "scope": "delete.book"}`

Comment: @ESG OAuth2 scopes are space delimited, so the scope is coming back as `write:book delete:book`

Comment: I came across a tutorial from Auth0 in which they develop a RequireHandler which splits the space delimited scopes.  I thought there'd be a built in solution to ASP.NET Core.
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization

Comment: I come across this example which also use IAuthorizationRequirement with extension method which is clearer to use in my opinion.  https://www.robin-gueldenpfennig.de/2018/11/evaluate-multi-value-scope-claim-in-asp-net-core-authorization-policy/

Answer (score 16):

You have to use a more complicated claim check. Use `RequireAssertion()` instead and parse out the scope claim:

```cs
var scopes = new[] { "write.book", "delete.book" };
builder.RequireAssertion(context => {
   var claim = context.User.FindFirst("scope");
   if(claim == null) { return false; }
   return claim.Value.Split(' ').Any(s =>
      scopes.Contains(s, StringComparer.Ordinal)
   );
});
```

I wrote a little extension method that, while less easy to read, is easier to use:

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> _scopeClaimTypes = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope",
    "scope"
};
public static AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireScope(this AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder, params string[] scopes) {
    return builder.RequireAssertion(context =>
        context.User
            .Claims
            .Where(c => _scopeClaimTypes.Contains(c.Type))
            .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Split(' '))
            .Any(s => scopes.Contains(s, StringComparer.Ordinal))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option for this is spliting scope into multiple claims

```cs
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new() { ValidateAudience = false };

                options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
                    {
                        if (context.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
                        {
                            var scopeClaims = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("scope");
                            if (scopeClaims is not null)
                            {
                                claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(scopeClaims);
                                claimsIdentity.AddClaims(scopeClaims.Value.Split(' ').Select(scope => new Claim("scope", scope)));
                            }
                        }
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

These extension methods I've created allows you to add scope policy where all scopes are required or any of the scopes

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Claims;

    public static class AuthorizationPolicyBuilder_Extentions
    {
        public static void AddPolicyScope_AllowedScopes(this AuthorizationOptions authorizationOptions, string policyName, params string[] allowedScopes) =>
            authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(policyName, policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("scope", allowedScopes));


        public static void AddPolicyScope_AllRequiredScopes(this AuthorizationOptions authorizationOptions, string policyName, params string[] requiredScopes) =>
            authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(policyName, policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireScopes(requiredScopes));

        private static AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireScopes(this AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder, params string[] requiredScopes) =>
             builder.RequireAssertion(context => {
                 var userScopes = GetUserScopes(context);
                 return requiredScopes.All(scope => userScopes.Contains(scope, StringComparer.CurrentCulture));
             });

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetUserScopes(this AuthorizationHandlerContext context) =>
            context?.User?
                    .Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type.Equals("scope"))
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Split(' ')) ?? new List<string>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope() extension method of HttpContext. It takes an array of string type scope values. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore#verify-scopes-conditionally).

```
 string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "write.book", "delete.book"};
 HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi);
```